# Pass Ajax POST variable to JQuery UI dialog

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Below is an Ajax `POST` variable I use to return some information to an ASP MVC3 View. However, I cannot get the `.dialg()` pop-up function to work. Right now you click on the icon that calls `GetProgramDetails(pgmname)`, and nothing happens. First time using Ajax, so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thx!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetProgramDetails(pgmname) {

        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/BatchPrograms/PopDetails',
            data: { programName: pgmname },
            dataType: 'html'
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            $('#data').dialog();
        });
</script>
```

EDIT

I've updated the `request.done` function to include a simple `alert` to see if the code was being called. After stepping through with Chrome's debugger, I saw that the code inside was completely skipped over.

```
    request.done(function (data) {
    alert("HERE!");
        $('#programExplanation').html(data);
    });
```

SECOND EDIT

Here is the controller code the ajax is returning a value from:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string PopDetails(string programName)
    {
        BatchPrograms batchprograms = db.BatchPrograms.Find(programName);
        if (batchprograms == null) return string.Empty;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append(batchprograms.ProgramName + " - " + batchprograms.ShortDescription);
        s.Append("<br />Job Names: " + batchprograms.PrdJobName + ", " + batchprograms.QuaJobName );
        s.Append("<br /> " + batchprograms.Description);
        return s.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: try my new post. it will try to open a dialog using the data js variable you got back. and cross your fingers!

Comment: Should that new block of code replace the `var request =` or the `request.done`, or be appended to either?

Comment: awesome, thx. Looks like this is more along the right path, however now it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Still no luck ... thx tho!

Comment: one last thing. i made mistake again. check code. if this dont work, im out of ideas

Comment: i guess it failed with $('#dialog').dialog('open');?

Comment: The innerHtml for the `dialog` div is blank, so maybe has something to do with the `.load()` part of the code?

Comment: add your PopDetails code to your post

Comment: Just added as the SECOND EDIT

Comment: if u set break point, does it hit the action method?

Comment: You mean `PopDetails`? If so then yes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the success method to handle the callback, like so:

```
var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/BatchPrograms/PopDetails',
        data: { programName: pgmname },
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function(data){ $('#data').dialog()} );
```

This will launch the dialog for you, but if you want to get the response data to work with it, you can have GetProgramDetails take a second parameter which is a callback for after the data is loaded like so:

```
function GetProgramDetails(pgmname, callback) {

    var request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/BatchPrograms/PopDetails',
        data: { programName: pgmname },
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(callback);
}
```

This way after the response is received you can handle what to do with the data in your implementation of the callback, in this case it seems like you will be setting data in the dialog and launching the dialog.

Comment: You are correct (I had never used the done function). But by adding the callback to the outer function it will allow him to better handle the response for the likely scenario of showing the data in the dialog.

Comment: Using the `.success(callback)` method you suggested, I tried to simply add this line of code to the `GetProgramDetails()` function: `$('#callback').dialog();`, which did not work. What is the syntax to use `callback` after the Ajax call?

Comment: You can pass a function into the method by assigning the function to a variable... var handleCallback = function(data){ /* do stuff here */ }; then pass handleCallback into your GetProgramDetails function as the callback parameter.